# Full text search with weighted ranking on foreign key and count

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to perform a full text search that includes weighted ranking on a foreign key and a count using PostgreSQL/TypeORM. I already have weighted tsvectors for the title, description, and message attributes in my main Strategy entity/table. Below is a diagram of my data model:

[image: ER Diagram]

The strategy entity can have multiple tags. It also has an attribute for the amount of times the strategy was used which I'd like to use as a weight. How do I include these foreign key tags and the use count in the text search ranking? Thanks in advance.

I also provided the code inspiration I used to set up add the tsvectors for my tables:

Weighted tsvector: https://github.com/benawad/postgres-full-text-search/blob/master/src/migration/1552096655610-SetupFullTextSearch.ts

Searching using weight tsvectors: https://github.com/benawad/postgres-full-text-search/blob/master/src/index.ts